# Add flow line based on data to Leaflet.canvas-Flowmaplayer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

So I am integrating my data with this flow map example used with Leaflet.JS here
https://github.com/jwasilgeo/Leaflet.Canvas-Flowmap-Layer

One issue i've run into is being able to draw the flowline based on a value in the data. So if its 10 tons shipped from one place to another, the line is 1pt in width, but if its 100 tons shipped the line is 10pts in width.

From the source file CanvasFlowmapLayer.js, [found here](https://github.com/jwasilgeo/Leaflet.Canvas-Flowmap-Layer/blob/master/src/CanvasFlowmapLayer.js), it looks like the width of the line is drawn statically here:

```
        type: 'simple',
        symbol: {
          // use canvas styling options (compare to CircleMarker styling below)
          strokeStyle: 'rgba(255, 0, 51, 0.8)',
          lineWidth: 1,
          lineCap: 'round',
          shadowColor: 'rgb(255, 0, 51)',
          shadowBlur: 1.5
        }
      },
```

I tried changing the lineWidth to the column of my data by doing this:
`lineWidth: 'e_vol',`
but nothing changes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!